# Why can't I get the correct reply from the python server running in docker？

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I ran a server written in python3 in docker, but I couldn't get the reply correctly, why？

The server code:

```
import socket


s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("0.0.0.0",10000))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    cur, add = s.accept()
    cur.sendall(b"hello")
    cur.close()
```

the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:

  python:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: python_Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"
```

the python_Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir /app/data
COPY test.py /app
CMD ["python", "-u", "test.py"]
```

Comment: how you test the commection, could you provide the command you tried

Comment: Maybe you should expose port `10000` on you Dockerfile

Comment: @SeddikOmar `EXPOSE` does not expose the port by default. Using `-p` to attach container's port to host's port will work even you haven't exposed it at `Dockerfile`. [Read more](https://forums.docker.com/t/what-is-the-use-of-expose-in-docker-file/37726/2)

Comment: @LinSel I used a tcp test software, but when I tried another software and the client that I wrote, there is no message

Comment: I tried it with `telnet localhost 10000`and it works

Comment: @leopal if you test your code on local you will have `http response invalid` you should use http header like : `cur.sendall(b'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 11\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\nHello World\r\n')
`